# undefined subroutine @main::csv error in Text:CSV_XS module

Tags: perl, csv, text

In one of my linux vm boxes the following perl code is failing at line 4

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } );
open( $fh, '<:crlf', 'test.csv' ) or die $!;
@lineArray = csv(   in => $fh, headers => "auto"); 
print 'done';
```

The error states that there is no csv method in main . Errors out as @main::csv undefined subroutine.
This code is working on other installation but not just on one machine.

Perl version is 5.10.1

Comment: What version of the module is installed on the box? Seems like an older version without the `csv` function. Also note that the constructor is not needed when using the `csv` function.

Comment: I just tested on v5.10 and v5.16 with the example copied from docs and it behaves the same way you say -- no `csv` function.

Comment: Yea I realized Text::CSV_XS was released in March 2016 after Oct, 2001. That's after 15 years. So I guess that's the reason , there is no csv method in one of my box because the module is old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csv` function in `Text::CSV_XS` [was introduced in version 1.04](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Text-CSV_XS). Check the value of `$Text::CSV_XS::VERSION` and upgrade if it is older than v1.04.